# Why do I have to update my node version if I am up to date?

Tags: nodes, full-node, daemon

So a few months ago I unplugged my bitcoin node when it was running perfectly. So when I connected it again this week I had to let it sync to the blockchain again. Now you can see it's synced but I have several issues.
It tells me to update the version when v0.19.0.1 is totally up to date. And if I need to update, how do I do it?
Secondly I don't know but it says that my node is unreachable (I cropped out the IP address). How can I fix it?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your node is not up to date: the latest release of Bitcoin Core is [`0.19.1`](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.19.1) which is a newer release than `0.19.0.1`.

You appear to be using a RaspiBolt. The RaspiBolt project's FAQ addresses your question here: [How to upgrade Bitcoin Core?](https://stadicus.github.io/RaspiBolt/raspibolt_faq.html#how-to-upgrade-bitcoin-core).

Regarding the reachability, your best bet is likely to raise an issue on the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/Stadicus/RaspiBolt/issues) (which it appears that you have done already).
There are some issues asking about nodes being unreachable on the project's github page, but I don't know more about that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on updating. The unreachable issue I think it's because of port forwarding